# How can I add a box to edit Order on a regular post?

Tags: posts, admin, post-editor, order

I'm currently using the menu_order field in the DB to have some custom ordering of posts. I want to expose this field to the user via the admin section, like it is when editing a Page (in Page Attributes).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse31629_init' );
function wpse31629_init()
{
    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );
}
```

Add that to your `functions.php` or in a [plugin file](https://gist.github.com/1301501) and you'll get an attributes dialog box with the menu order input.

Comment: @Ben This IS the exact interface you're asking for.

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the exact interface you're asking for, but you might like this.

http://drewgourley.com/order-up-custom-ordering-for-wordpress/

It modifies the 'menu_order' field the same way you are, and it also allows you to set an option to auto sort all queries from specific post types, so you don't have to manually set the 'orderby' and 'order' arguments when getting posts.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing a lot of custom ordering in code, so I don't want to use a plugin that will mess with that.